# Failing AzureDevOps build pipeline if number of warnings exceeds a certain limit

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm fanatic about not getting the project quality out of control.

I understand that at certain cases warnings might make sense but i'm concerned that the number of warnings will increase over time.

I have an Azure DevOps build (gated commit) pipeline and i want to allow only 10 warnings so that at some point developers will have to address their warnings.

Is there a way to count the warnings and block the pipeline if the warnings count exceeds a certain number?

Thanx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to count the warnings and block the pipeline if the warnings count exceeds a certain number?

The answer is yes.

There is a great extension to meet your needs：[**Build Quality Checks**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.BuildQualityChecks). It provides a wealth of build quality checks, and you can add these build quality checks to your build process.

There is an option **Warning Threshold**， which could be used to specify **the maximum number of warnings. The build will fail if this number is exceeded.**

[image]

And even if the policy breaks the build, you could still get test results as well as the compile output.

Comment: damn, this looks great!!! exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I would recommend **treating warnings as error** so that your gated commit will fail if the project contains warnings - here an example for dotnet core:

```
dotnet build /warnaserror
```

Developers still have the option to *disable* a warning in certain cases:

```
#pragma warning disable CS8632
// Here I do something that nullable references without context but I know what I do because...
#pragma warning restore CS8632
```

Comment: yes, that's an option, if i can't get it exactly the way i want :-)

Comment: I think it is the same switch